# RewriteRule overrides ProxyPass

Tags: apache-httpd, reverse-proxy, mod-rewrite

On a centos 7 machine, I'd like to run a python server alongside an apache server. I figured the easiest way would be to configure apache as a reverse proxy. This is my VirtualHost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot /home/username/mydomain/src
        ServerName mydomain.com
        ErrorLog logs/mydomain-error_log
        CustomLog logs/mydomain-access_log common
        DirectoryIndex index.php

    <Directory /home/username/mydomain/src>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml
    </Directory>


    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /mediaproxy http://127.0.0.1:9001/mediaproxy
    ProxyPassReverse /mediaproxy http://127.0.0.1:9001/mediaproxy

    LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^/api/media/(.*) /data/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^/api/v1/* /api/v1/index.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^/assets/(.*) /site/v1/content/assets/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^/css/(.*) /site/v1/content/css/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^/js/(.*) /site/v1/content/js/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^/fonts/(.*) /site/v1/content/fonts/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^/* /index.php [L] # problematic rule

    // lets encrypt entries
```

Now, my problem is that rewrite rules takes precedence over ProxyPass. That ism when I visit mydomain.com/mediaproxy/somepage, it serves the content at `/index.php`, specified with `RewriteRule ^/* /index.php [L]` . Reverse proxy works correctly if I remove the problematic rule. Unfortunately I need to keep it.

How do I tell apache to use `ProxyPass` rule first, and use `RewriteRule` only if there is no match?

Comment: Set conditional oroxypass rules that are opposite to the rewriterule conditions. Then remove the corresponding conditions from rewriterule. The result is that you proxy everything _except_ the selected patterns, which then fall through to the rewrite logic. If I have time tomorrow I'll dig out a similar block of code from my own Apache/tomcat config

Comment: Thanks for stopping by. I just figured it out.

Comment: I'm seeing the opposite behavior. I have a rewrite rule that matches the agent string of several bots. When they access the ProxyPass URLs, the rewrite rules are bypassed; the bots are accessing the proxied material.  My rewrite rules appear before the ProxyPass entries. Order might be important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Just add [P] to the rewrite rule and it start to behave as reverse proxy

```
ProxyPass /mediaproxy http://127.0.0.1:9001/mediaproxy
ProxyPassReverse /mediaproxy http://127.0.0.1:9001/mediaproxy
```

is functionally the same as:

```
RewriteRule /mediaproxy http://127.0.0.1:9001/mediaproxy [P]
```

but the catch all rewrite rule is not triggered.

Comment: Excellent! Better then my own suggestion I think

Comment: please remember to accept your own answer, since it is what resolved your issue

Answer (score 1):

Add a `RewriteCond` to your problematic `RewriteRule` to exclude the case of accessing the path used in `ProxyPass`:

```
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" !^/mediaproxy.*
RewriteRule ^/.* /index.php [L]
```

Thus, your "problematic" `RewriteRule` will not match any URL starting with "/mediaproxy".